# Matrix manipulation to extract certain sub columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

```
M = [1007  1007  4044  1007  4044  1007  5002 5002 5002 622 622;
      552   552   300   552   300   552   431  431  431 124 124 ; 
     2010  2010  1113  2010  1113  2010  1100 1100 1100  88  88;
        7    12    25    15    12    30     2   10   55  32  12]

X = {[2 5 68 44],[2 10 55 9 17],[1 55 6 7 8 9],[32 12]}

A = [1007  4044  5002  622
      552   300   431  124
     2010  1113  1100   88
        7    25     2   32
       12    12    10   12
       15          55
       30                 ]
```

`A` is an entity to explain what I want.

`A` contains unique column vectors of `M(1:3,:)`, in addition to the corresponding values in `M(4,:)`

```
A(1:3,:) = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows')'
```

I hope to find the column vectors of `A(1:3,:)` whose the corresponding values in `M(4,:)` are not part of one of the vectors of the cell `X` (and obviously not equal to one of these vectors).

for my example the desired result is the matrix:

```
 [1007  4044; 
   552   300; 
  2010  1113;]
```

the column vector `[5002;431;1100]` was eliminated because `[2;10;55]` is contained in `X{2} = [2 10 55 9 17]`

the column vector `[622;124;88]` was eliminated because `[32 12] = X{4}`

Comment: Have you tried to do it using loops yet?

Comment: @Dan: I look for a solution without loops, because my matrix has a size greater than 1000000 !!

Comment: start with loops and get that right first. Then if it *is* too slow, post your code here and maybe someone can help optimize it. But as it stands, you're just asking for code without showing that you've tried to tackle the problem yourself.

Comment: If you really want to try it without loops (but I strongly recommend you start with loops first), then off the top of my head I would look at using `accumarray` to build the rest of your `A` matrix (excluding those first three rows, and keeping it as a separate matrix), you will probably find the other outputs from your `unique` statements helpful in generating the inputs you'll need for `accumarray`

Answer (score 1):

**Inputs:**

```
M = [1007  1007  4044  1007  4044  1007  5002 5002 5002 622 622;
      552   552   300   552   300   552   431  431  431 124 124; 
     2010  2010  1113  2010  1113  2010  1100 1100 1100  88  88;
        7    12    25    15    12    30     2   10   55  32  12];

X = {[2 5 68 44],[2 10 55 9 17],[1 55 6 7 8 9],[32 12]};
```

Doing this (what you have done)

```
A(1:3,:) = unique(M(1:3,:).','rows').';
```

gives:

```
>> A

A =

     622        1007        4044        5002
     124         552         300         431
      88        2010        1113        1100
```

Then using `unique` and `accumarray`

```
[~, ~, subs] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows');

A4 = accumarray(subs(:),M(4,:).',[],@(x) {x});
```

Now we have `A4` as cell-array

```
>> A4

A4 = 

[2x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [3x1 double]
```

Then using `cellfun`, `ismember`, `all` and `any`

```
%// getting a mask of which columns we want
idxC(length(A4)) = false;
for ii = 1:length(A4)
    idxC(ii) = ~any(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(A4{ii},x)), X));
end
```

Displaying the columns we want

```
out = A(:,idxC)
```

**Results:**

```
>> out

out =

    1007        4044
     552         300
    2010        1113
```

I kindly recommend you try it yourself as @Dan suggests. If you are stuck at somewhere, you could refer this. If you have any clarification/modification, let me know :)

Comment: there is a problem, I think the loop should be on the length of A and not X !! because when I apply the code on my data I get: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions. 

Error in ==> @(x)all(ismember(A4{ii},x))


Error in ==>     idxC(ii) = ~any(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(A4{ii},x)), X)); but even in that case I get the same error

Comment: @bzak, thanks for pointing it out.. edited.. even when using `length(A4)`, are you getting error? can you upload the actual data you are using?

Comment: I think I found the problem, in my matrix M, there are several values of the first line that are repeated without belonging to the same vector of A(1:3,:). So in the code, we should consider: [~, ~, subs] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows'); instead of: [~, ~, subs] = unique(M(1,:));

Comment: yes it works, but the computing time between each iteration is 2 second. So if length(A4) = 20000, the calculation time will be 20000*2s !!!

Comment: why avoid the loop is difficult?

Comment: @bzak Loops are not always slow atleast after JIT implementation. I don't have any other way to do this.. have you completed one full run for your actual size? how much time does it take?

Comment: the program runs for more than one hour and he just passed ii = 3400