# How to avoid the loop to reduce the computation time of this code?

Tags: matlab, matrix, runtime, vectorization

how to avoid the loop to reduce the computation time of this code ([one solution of my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391956/matrix-manipulation-to-extract-certain-sub-columns/30394678?noredirect=1#comment48895269_30394678)):

I hope to find the column vectors of `A(1:3,:)` whose corresponding values in `M(4,:)` are not part of one of the vectors of the cell `X` (and obviously not equal to one of these vectors). I look for a fast solution if `X` is very large.

```
M = [1007  1007  4044  1007  4044  1007  5002 5002 5002 622 622;
      552   552   300   552   300   552   431  431  431 124 124; 
     2010  2010  1113  2010  1113  2010  1100 1100 1100  88  88;
        7    12    25    15    12    30     2   10   55  32  12];
```

Here I take directly `A`:

```
A = [1007  4044  5002  622;
      552   300   431  124;
     2010  1113  1100   88];
```

`A` contains unique column vectors of `M(1:3,:)`

```
X = {[2 5 68 44],[2 10 55 9 17],[1 55 6 7 8 9],[32 12]};

[~, ~, subs] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows');

A4 = accumarray(subs(:),M(4,:).',[],@(x) {x});

%// getting a mask of which columns we want
idxC(length(A4)) = false;
for ii = 1:length(A4)
    idxC(ii) = ~any(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(A4{ii},x)), X));
end
```

Displaying the columns we want

```
out = A(:,idxC)
```

Results:

```
>> out

out =

    1007        4044
     552         300
    2010        1113
```

the column vector `[5002;431;1100]` was eliminated because `[2;10;55]` is contained in `X{2} = [2 10 55 9 17]`

the column vector `[622;124;88]` was eliminated because `[32 12] = X{4}`

**Another example:** with the same `X`

```
    M = [1007  4044  1007  4044  1007  5002 5002 5002 622 622  1007  1007  1007;
          552   300   552   300   552   431  431  431 124 124   552    11    11; 
         2010  1113  2010  1113  2010  1100 1100 1100  88  88  2010    20    20;
           12    25    15    12    30     2   10   55  32  12     7    12     7];

X = {[2 5 68 44],[2 10 55 9 17],[1 55 6 7 8 9],[32 12]};

A = [1007  4044  5002  622  1077;
      552   300   431  124    11;
     2010  1113  1100   88    20];
```

**Results**: (with scmg answer)

I get if `A` sorted according to the first row: (correct result)

```
out =

         1007        1007        4044
           11         552         300
           20        2010        1113
```

if I do not sort the matrix `A`, I get: (false result)

```
out =

        4044        5002         622
         300         431         124
        1113        1100          88
```

the column vector `A(:,4) = [622;124;88]` should be eliminated because `[32 12] = X{4}`.

the column vector `[5002;431;1100]` should be eliminated because `[2;10;55]` is contained in `X{2} = [2 10 55 9 17]`

Comment: Could you explan the logic of how you obtain the output? That will save us time trying to deduce it from your code

Comment: @LuisMendo: I received two answer for my question. the scmg response  gives the rignt output, as in the example, but it requires a lot of computation time if X is very large.  The logic developed by Ben Voigt is interesting but the output result is false, and I can not find out why! input in my question are M, A and X and output is out = A(:,idxC)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I hope to find the column vectors of A(1:3,:) whose the corresponding values in M(4,:) are not part of one of the vectors of the cell X (and obviously not equal to one of these vectors). I look for a fast solution if X is very large.

Comment: Just to clarify: you mean "whose corresponding values in M(4,:) are not part of _the same_ vector of the cell X", right?

Comment: @LuisMendo: yes, the same vector of the cell X.

Comment: Maybe add that explanation in your question, so that you can get more help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer of Ben Voigt is great, but the line `for A4i = A4{ii}` is the one causing issues : the for loop doesn't work this way with column vectors :

```
%row vector
for i = 1:3
    disp('foo');
end

    foo
    foo
    foo

%column vector
for i = (1:3).'
    disp('foo');
end

    foo
```

Just try for `A4i = A4{ii}.'` instead and it should get your work done!

Now, if we look at the output :

```
A(:,idxC) =

    4044        5002
     300         431
    1113        1100
```

As you can see, the final result is not what we expected.

As long as `unique` does a kind of sort, the subs are not numbered by the order of encounter in A, but by order of encounter in C (which is sorted) :

```
subs =

 2
 2
 3
 2
 3
 2
 4
 4
 4
 1
 1
```

Therefore you should pass by the matrix given by `unique` rather than A to get your final output

Enter

```
[C, ~, subs] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows'); 
%% rather than [~, ~, subs] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows');
```

Then, to get the final output, enter

```
>> out = C(idxC,:).'
out =

        1007        4044
         552         300
        2010        1113
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, following your suggestion, I find as result : out = [A(:,2) A(:,3)] instead of the right result: out = [A(:,1) A(:,2)]

Comment: I approve this clarifying answer.  How can one make the loop work on both row and column vectors?  Perhaps something like `A4{ii}(:)'` ?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why you don't get the right result 
@Ben Voigt : yup this would actually work as long as (:) put everything in column

Comment: The transpose operation is `.'` and not `'` ! Using only `'` does the complex conjugate transpose, which is a different operation and cause wrong results.

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior: Thank you very much for the effort you put in trying to help me. Now, I get the result of the example, but with my real data I get a false result, whereas with scmg answer, I get the right result !!! my problem with scmg answer is the computation time when X is very large.

Comment: Have you tried this method (using `A(:,idxC) on your big data. Because it looks like even scmg code gives a wrong answer on this example, making me this that your example have a problem

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior: I tried both methods A(:,idxC) and C(idxC,:).'  on my big data and I find wrong results! and what I find strange is that only the scmg code gives me the right result for both exemple and my real data !!!

Comment: Okay, gonna search for it

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you should not be trying to eliminate loops.  The vectorization is actually hurting you badly.

In particular (giving a name to your anonymous lambda)

```
issubset = @(x) all(ismember(A4{ii},x))
```

is ridiculously inefficient, because it doesn't short-circuit.  Replace that with a loop.

Same for

```
any(cellfun(issubset, X))
```

Use an approach similar to this instead:

```
idxC = true(size(A4));
NX = numel(X);
for ii = 1:length(A4)
    for jj = 1:NX
        xj = X{jj};
        issubset = true;
        for A4i=A4{ii}
            if ~ismember(A4i, xj)
                issubset = false;
                break;
            end;
        end;
        if issubset
            idxC(ii) = false;
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

The two `break` statements, and especially the second one, trigger an early exit that potentially saves you a huge amount of computation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think xj = X{jj}; instead of xj = X{j}; 
and I get the error message: ??? Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Error in ==>  idxC{ii} = false;

Comment: Yeah those should have been parentheses not braces

Comment: I think there is a problem! For the example, out = A(:,idxC) gives out =

   Empty matrix: 3-by-0

Comment: your answer is fast but it gives a false result, I think there is an error in your code

Comment: What do you mean by  "for A4i=A4{ii}" .The loop is done on ??? I can not find the error in your code!

Comment: @bzak: I expect `A4i` to take on each of the values contained in `A4{ii}`.  If that's causing problems, you can loop through the indexes and assign `A4i` inside the loop, using `A4{ii}` and your index loop variable.

Comment: I think your code tries to eliminate A4{ii} if at least one component of A4{ii} belongs to a vector X{jj} , while the goal of the question is to eliminate A4{ii} if all components of A4{ii} belongs to a vector  X{jj} !

Comment: @bzak: There are two shortcuts.  One, if any element of an A4{ii} is not found in X{jj}, don't test the remaining parts of A4{ii}, start over with the next jj.  Secondly, if all elements of an A4{ii} are found in any X{jj}, don't test the remaining values of jj, remove that A4{ii} already.

Comment: but why your code does not give the expected result from the example? while with the other answer I get the right result!

Answer (score 3):

**Shot #1**

Listed in this section is an approach that is supposed to be a quick and *direct* approach to solve our case. Please note that since `A` is the matrix of unique columns from `M` considering upto the third row, it is skipped here as the input because we generate it internally with the solution code. This is maintained in the next approach/shot as well. Here's the implementation -

```
function out = shot1_func(M,X)

%// Get unique columns and corresponding subscripts
[unqrows, ~, subs_idx] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows');
unqcols = unqrows.'; %//'

counts = accumarray(subs_idx(:),1); %// Counts of each unique subs_idx

%// Modify each cell of X based on their relevance with the fourth row of M
X1 = cellfun(@(x) subs_idx(ismember(M(4,:),x)),X,'Uni',0);

lensX = cellfun('length',X1); %// Cell element count of X1

Xn = vertcat(X1{:}); %// Numeric array version of X
N = max(subs_idx);   %// Number of unique subs_idx

%// Finally, get decision mask to select the correst columns from unqcols
sums = cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,Xn,1:N),1);
cumsums_at_shifts = sums(cumsum(lensX),:);

mask1 = any(bsxfun(@eq,diff(cumsums_at_shifts,[],1),counts(:).'),1); %//'
decision_mask = mask1 | cumsums_at_shifts(1,:) == counts(:).';    %//'
out = unqcols(:,~decision_mask);

return
```

---

**Shot #2**

The earlier mentioned approach might have a bottleneck at :

`cellfun(@(x) subs_idx(ismember(M4,x)),X,'Uni',0)`

So, alternatively to keep performance as a good motivation, one can separate out the whole process into two stages. The first stage could take care of cells of `X` that are not repeated in the fourth row of `M`, which could be implemented with a vectorized approach and another stage solving for the rest of `X's` cells with our slower `cellfun` based approach.

Thus, the code would bloat out a bit, but hopefully would be better with performance. The final implementation would look something like this -

```
%// Get unique columns and corresponding subscripts
[unqrows, ~, subs_idx] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows')
unqcols = unqrows.' %//'
counts = accumarray(subs_idx,1);

%// Form ID array for X
lX = cellfun('length',X)
X_id = zeros(1,sum(lX))
X_id([1 cumsum(lX(1:end-1)) + 1]) = 1
X_id = cumsum(X_id)

Xr = cellfun(@(x) x(:).',X,'Uni',0); %//'# Convert to cells of row vectors
X1 = [Xr{:}]                         %// Get numeric array version

%// Detect cells that are to be processed by part1 (vectorized code)
[valid,idx1] = ismember(M(4,:),X1)
p1v = ~ismember(1:max(X_id),unique(X_id(accumarray(idx1(valid).',1)>1))) %//'

X_part1 = Xr(p1v)
X_part2 = Xr(~p1v)

%// Get decision masks from first and second passes and thus the final output
N = size(unqcols,2);
dm1 = first_pass(X_part1,M(4,:),subs_idx,counts,N)
dm2 = second_pass(X_part2,M(4,:),subs_idx,counts)
out = unqcols(:,~dm1 & ~dm2)
```

Associated functions -

```
function decision_mask = first_pass(X,M4,subs_idx,counts,N)

lensX = cellfun('length',X)'; %//'# Get X cells lengths
X1 = [X{:}];                  %// Extract cell data from X

%// Finally, get the decision mask
vals = changem(X1,subs_idx,M4) .* ismember(X1,M4);

sums = cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,vals(:),1:N),1);
cumsums_at_shifts = sums(cumsum(lensX),:);
mask1 = any(bsxfun(@eq,diff(cumsums_at_shifts,[],1),counts(:).'),1); %//'
decision_mask = mask1 | cumsums_at_shifts(1,:) == counts(:).';    %//'
return


function decision_mask = second_pass(X,M4,subs_idx,counts)

%// Modify each cell of X based on their relevance with the fourth row of M
X1 = cellfun(@(x) subs_idx(ismember(M4,x)),X,'Uni',0);

lensX = cellfun('length',X1); %// Cell element count of X1

Xn = vertcat(X1{:}); %// Numeric array version of X
N = max(subs_idx);   %// Number of unique subs_idx

%// Finally, get decision mask to select the correst columns from unqcols
sums = cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,Xn,1:N),1);
cumsums_at_shifts = sums(cumsum(lensX),:);

mask1 = any(bsxfun(@eq,diff(cumsums_at_shifts,[],1),counts(:).'),1); %//'
decision_mask = mask1 | cumsums_at_shifts(1,:) == counts(:).';       %//'

return
```

---

**Verficication**

This section lists code to verify the output. Here's the code to do so to verify the shot #1 code -

```
%// Setup inputs and output
load('matrice_data.mat');   %// Load input data
X = cellfun(@(x) unique(x).',X,'Uni',0); %// Consider X's unique elements
out = shot1_func(M,X); %// output with Shot#1 function

%// Accumulate fourth row data from M based on the uniqueness from first 3 rows
[unqrows, ~, subs] = unique(M(1:3,:)','rows');    %//'
unqcols = unqrows.';                              %//'
M4 = accumarray(subs(:),M(4,:).',[],@(x) {x});    %//'
M4 = cellfun(@(x) unique(x),M4,'Uni',0);

%// Find out cells in M4 that correspond to unique columns unqcols
[unqcols_idx,~] = find(pdist2(unqcols.',out.')==0);

%// Finally, verify output
for ii = 1:numel(unqcols_idx)
    for jj = 1:numel(X)
        if all(ismember(M4{unqcols_idx(ii)},X{jj}))
            error('Error: Wrong output!')
        end
    end
end
disp('Success!')
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82601/discussion-between-divakar-and-bzak).

Comment: I saved my real M and X data in a file, and I applied directly your answer to this data (input: M and X), and I get exactly as output the matrix A. But with the data from the example I get the right result, I find this completely strange !!!

Comment: I added another example with M slightly modified. With your code instead of getting [A(:,5)  A(:,1)  A(:,2)], I get [A(:,4)  A(:,5)  A(:,1)  A(:,2)]. the column vector A(:,4) = [622;124;88] should be eliminated because [32 12] = X{4}.

Comment: @bzak Check out the edits? See if it works for your actual case?

Comment: @bzak In case, input `X` to functions `first_pass` or `second_pass` is an empty cell array, it might throw error. If it does, add this code snippet at the top of those two functions: http://pastebin.com/t5uSTWPU

Comment: Thank you very much Divakar for the effort you put in trying to help me. The code applied to the example gives the right result but with my real data I still get a wrong result! Is there a way here to send you my real data ?

Comment: @bzak Upload it to some site like dropbox and link it here? Would it be okay to share that way?

Comment: @bzak I think I got it working! Well, there were duplicates within some of the cells in `X`. So, if you do `X = cellfun(@(x) unique(x),X,'Uni',0);` and then run my code, it seems to be working. Let me know if you get it to work too?

Comment: @bzak Still wrong? You mean with some other data? Because with the dropbox linked data, I have checked, it seems to give the correct result after that edit.

Comment: you found the same results as in matrice_Correct_result ?

Comment: @bzak Well I checked against scmg's solution output. His code is something like this I think - http://pastebin.com/7wgETMZF. Can you check if I used his code correctly? Or did you make some changes to his code?

Comment: @bzak Can you check if I have used scmg's solution code correctly here - http://pastebin.com/7wgETMZF ?

Comment: @bzak Can you copy and paste scmg's code, the way you are using in a new pastebin link and share with me?

Comment: Sorry Divakar! I use A(1:3,:) = N(1:3,:); for A. In this case  A is sorted according to the first line and the third line

Comment: @bzak And how would I get `N`? How can I get it from `M`? I am assuming `X` and `M` to be the only inputs.

Comment: it is in the file matrice_data

Comment: @bzak But how would I create `N` for a generic case. For example, for the given sample case of `X` and `M` in the question, how can I create `N` or `A`?

Comment: at the beginning, I introduced the matrix A Just to explain what I want to find, this is not an input! it is deduced from another matrix, but it corresponds to unique(M(1:3,:).','rows').'  if  we not take into account the order of columns. I'm sorry for the confusion!  So, A  In this case should be sorted according to the first line and the third line.

Comment: A  is formed from the unique columns of M (1:3,:) and should be sorted according to the first line and the third line.

Comment: @bzak Do you have a code that generates `A` from `M`, because I am not getting it?

Comment: No, A is not deducted directly from M, but there is another intermediate matrix that has the same columns of M(1:3,:) !

Comment: you are right Divakar. I had checked result 'out' only by comparing the corresponding values on the 4th row and the 5th row of N !

Comment: Why all answers gives a correct result with the example of my question and a false result with my real data !!? what can you advise me now?

Comment: @bzak Well I think my Shot #1 works with the real data as long as you don't bring in `N` into my code, as I am already finding unique columns using `unique(...,'rows')`. I would suggest using my Shot #1 and check if you see any irregularity. Let me know what you think and if this sounds like a good debugging plan?

Comment: @bzak And use `X = cellfun(@(x) unique(x).',X,'Uni',0);` before using my code.

Comment: I share the code to find X and to check if X is correct by seeking the result 'out' . Can you please verify if there is any problem with this code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e2qkzrwkla5glq4/AACGds3mFGzdEZfwmNWwo1TEa?dl=0

Comment: @bzak Not sure what you meant by checking if X is correct by seeking the result 'out', but I can tell you how to verify `out`, for which I have just added code at the end of the solution. Let me know what you think!

Comment: I think that may be my problem is how I find X. In test_Divakar.m, there are at the beginning the code to find X, it is not complicated. Can you just tell me if it is correct !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use 2 times `cellfun`:

```
idxC = cellfun(@(a) ~any(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(a,x)), X)), A4, 'un', 0);
idxC = cell2mat(idxC);
out = A(:,idxC)
```

Comment: yes, at first you should avoid using `cellfun` and use for-loop instead like the other answer, until everything is correct, only then you could try to vertorize part by part. I just wanted to point out that you can use cellfun 2 times together, but the correctness depends on your real problem, in which you must adapt it yourself.